# In place hold in O365, not clear how preservation hold library works

Tags: sharepoint-online, retention

I started a job in an org that implemented the in hold retention policy across the board (all elements in O365). 
 This caused the automatic creation in every SharePoint site collection (including the site collections sitting behind teams and groups) of the Preservation hold library that keeps a copy of every file deleted and every file (allegedly) edited.

I say allegedly because I am testing it and more than 24 hours ago I edited a file and **I cannot see the 'copy' of my most recent editing.** Beside the fact that this setting in place is not fit for purpose.

Does anyone know how it should work from experience (and not Microsoft official documentation)?